# Proof that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an Integral Domain iff $p$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The proposition given in my lecture notes is:

> $\mathbb Z_p$ is an integral domain iff $p$ is prime.

The first part of the proof is written as follows:

Suppose the integer n is not a prime and $n=ab$ where $1<a$, $b<n$. Then $ab = 0$ mod $n$.

To me this only proves that $\mathbb Z_p$ is not an integral domain when p is not prime since there are zero divisors. Could someone correct my interpretation?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. That part proves "$\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain $\Rightarrow p$ is prime". The other direction should be proved afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, and that provides a proof of half of the statement. The fact that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is not an integral domain when $p$ is not prime is the contrapositive of the statement that if $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain then $p$ is prime.

Comment: Ahh I see - the contrapositive tripped me up, thanks.